# I Get the error message while write data in file --Cannot access the disposable object .Object name :MS.internal.InternalMemorystream

Tags: c#, silverlight

This was the code:

```
 public static void SaveFile(Stream stream, string fileName = "")
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = file.CreateFile(fileName);

            var filesize = stream.Length;
            var getContent = new byte[(int)filesize];
            stream.Read(getContent, 0, (int)filesize);
            fs.Write(getContent, 0, (int)filesize);

            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to fix your question for us to answer it.

Comment: Are you sure the error message is not this: "Cannot access a disposed object"?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong with the code you've posted.  The fault is in the code you are using to call this function.  Most likely you are passing a `Stream` which has been disposed prematurely.